# SQL Server select records from header and body table

Tags: sql-server, union

I have 2 tables, *Header* and *Body*, with the same columns and multiple groups of records. For each group, I want one record of header and the rest of the body records.

#### Header

```
Id Group Name Value
1  1     n1   v1
2  2     n2   v2
```

#### Body

```
Id Group Name Value
1  1     nb1   vb1
2  1     nb2   vb2
3  2     nb3   vb3
```

#### Expected Result

```
Id Group Name Value
1  1     n1    v1
2  1     nb1   vb1
3  1     nb2   vb2
4  2     n2    v2
5  2     nb3   vb3
```

If it was just one group I could have just done a union but the number of groups isn't fixed.

The `Id` column in the result is just a row number. The other three columns `Group`, `Name`, and `Value` are more important to me.

The header row is always the first row for that group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why this won't work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Header', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Header;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Body', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Body;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Header
(
    iGroup int
    , sName varchar(50)
    , iValue int
);
CREATE TABLE Body
(
    iGroup int
    , sName varchar(50)
    , iValue int
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Header (iGroup, sName, iValue)
VALUES (1, 'test1', 10)
    , (2, 'test2', 20);

INSERT INTO dbo.Body (iGroup, sName, iValue)
VALUES (1, 'test3', 30)
    , (2, 'test4', 40);


;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT iGroup
        , sName
        , iValue
        , 0 as sort_by
    FROM Header
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT iGroup
        , sName
        , iValue
        , 1 as sort_by
    FROM Body
)
SELECT Id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sort_by, iGroup, sName)
    , src.*
FROM src
ORDER BY sort_by, iGroup, sName;
```

Results:

```
╔════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ Id ║ iGroup ║ sName ║ iValue ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║      1 ║ test1 ║     10 ║
║  2 ║      1 ║ test3 ║     30 ║
║  3 ║      2 ║ test2 ║     20 ║
║  4 ║      2 ║ test4 ║     40 ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

Also, don't use reserved keywords as column names, please!

Answer (score 1):

A UNION ALL plus ROW_NUMBER() do the job.

> ```
> create table header ([Id] int, [Group] int, [Name] varchar(10), [Value] varchar(10));
> insert into header values
> (1, 1, 'n1', 'v1'),
> (2, 2, 'n2', 'v2');
>
> create table body ([Id] int, [Group] int, [Name] varchar(10), [Value] varchar(10));
> insert into body values
> (1, 1, 'nb1', 'vb1'),
> (2, 1, 'nb2', 'vb2'),
> (3, 2, 'nb3', 'vb3');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select row_number() over (order by [Id], [Group]) rn,
>        [Group], [Name], [Value]
> from
>      (
>       select [Id], [Group], [Name], [Value]
>       from   header
>       union all
>       select [Id], [Group], [Name], [Value]
>       from   body
>      ) x
> order by [Id], [Group]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> rn | Group | Name | Value
> :- | ----: | :--- | :----
> 1  |     1 | n1   | v1   
> 2  |     1 | nb1  | vb1  
> 3  |     1 | nb2  | vb2  
> 4  |     2 | n2   | v2   
> 5  |     2 | nb3  | vb3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=93a0d764a2e6edfadff38f3cbc8d63b5)*